# How do change white spaces within CDATA to non-white space characters i.e. crlf to \n

Tags: xslt, transform, cdata

VB2008 and VB2010 on Windows 7.

I am getting XML from an external source that needs to be written to a file.  The XML contains a lot of CDATA's with white space characters such as new line CR LF's, etc. (i.e. 13 and 10's). This file is written via a WriteAllText and then read by another program.

The control characters screws up the output filse that is created.

I have tried to manipulate the contents of the CDATA and just do a replace but the file is so big that it takes about 20 minutes on a 3.6g machine so it is just not practical.

Need a way to convert the 13's and 10's into \n, etc and not takes a long time.

The 2nd VB2010 program uses
Transform As New XslCompiledTransform  .....

Any ideas?

Comment: The XML parser should normalise CRLF, CR or LF to a single LF (#10) The only way to get character 13 in the input as seen by XSLT is to have an explicit numeric reference `&13;`

Comment: Please show the code you are using to *"manipulate the contents of the CDATA"* that takes so long. How is the data presented on its arrival? Are you processing with XSLT before writing to disk?

Comment: Not using a XMLReader, etc.  Program 1 is just getting the response and writing to disk, program 2 just doing a transform via the XSLT file to product a tab delimited text file.  We really do not want to have to inspect each node via a XMLReader.     

We were able to reduce the item to inspect each CDATA and replace the control characters with \n, etc.  which is working.

It would have been good if there was just an easier way.